# MIPS floating point add

Tags: assembly, floating-point, double, mips

I'm trying to make a simple function that adds to floats passed as arguments in MIPS. Previously I did a simple code to add ints:

```
   move    v0,a0      
   add     v0,v0,a1   
   j       ra
```

Copying it I did something alike for floats

```
    l.d $f0,0($a0)
    l.d $f2,0($a1)
    add.d $f0,$f0,$f2
    j ra
```

Which results in a compiling error:

```
Error: illegal operands `l.d'
```

Which I'm guessing is because of how I'm trying to get the arguments from a0. How am I suppossed to receive double floating point arguments, adding them and returning them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you passing the arguments to the function?

Comment: @Michael `a0` and `a1` point to two doubles?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: In the integer case the OP seemed to pass the arguments by value. It's not clear whether he/she is still doing that, or has switched to passing by address for the floating point version. That's why I'm asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw my mistake. Had to pass them by reference and respect the ABI :)
Thanks

Comment: Answers exist for answers, not for comments or for saying thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze well...the answer (or hint which lead me to it) was within the comments. Thought it was appropiate to point out that indeed the arguments were the problems and mark this as solved.

Comment: Then you could ask Michael to make his comment the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ldc1` instead of `l.d`. `l.d` is most likely a macro and for some reason it's not defined/available.